# Nested attributes with tabs (has_many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I'm working with tabs lately, and after some experiments, I've decided to adapt one tab to show one or more instancies of one model (Contact). Well, following the steps of fields_for, created some tab-pane, under tab-content that's under the principal. The logic is :

Dados Básicos | Endereço | Contatos

(Contact 1)(Contact 2)(Contact 3)...

After the nav-pills, should be showing the respective Contact, but it show nothing. Is there any problem in routing? (With the #contact-... etc)

```
<div class="inner">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#dados" data-toggle="tab">Dados Básicos</a>  </li>
  <li><a href="#adresses" data-toggle="tab">Endereço</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contacts" data-toggle="tab">Contatos</a></li>
</ul>
...
<div class="tab-content">
 <div class="tab-pane" id="contacts">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <% @customer.contacts.each_with_index do |co, i| %>
    <% if i==0 %><li class="active"><% else %><li><% end %>
    <a href="#contact-<%= i %>"><%= co.nome %></a></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <%= f.fields_for :contacts do |k| %>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="contact-<%= k.index %>">
      <div class="well">   
        <%= k.hidden_field :id %>

        <%= k.label :nome, "Nome" %>
        <%= k.text_field :nome, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= k.label :setor, "Setor" %>
        <%= k.text_field :setor, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= k.label :email, "Email" %>
        <%= k.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= k.label :observacao, "Observação" %>
        <%= k.text_area :observacao, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= k.fields_for :telephones do |tel| %>
          <%= tel.hidden_field :id %>
          <%= tel.label :telefone, "Telefone" %>
          <%= tel.text_field :telefone, class: 'form-control' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit "Salvar Alterações", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Can you try `telephone` rather than `telephones` in your `k.fields_for :`

Comment: run "rake routes" on your console. It will show you your routes. It is always better that you put your routes dinamically than directly on the href of the link. I suggest you do: <%= link_to contacts_path(co) %> inside each <li>